# error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'latout_height' in package 'android' の意味を教えてください

Tags: android, java

> error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'latout_height' in
>   package 'android'

javaを利用していたところこのようなエラーが発生しました。解決方法を教えていだだけますか。

Comment: どういう状況でエラーが出たのか、もっと詳しく書きましょう。何を使っていてエラーが出たのか、どういう画面でエラーが出たのか。回答する人が質問をすんなり理解できるように書くと、回答をもらいやすくなります。

Answer (score 3):

スペルミスが原因です。

`latout_height`ではなく`layout_height`とすればエラーがなくなりませんか？

Answer (score 2):

エラーメッセージを読んでも原因が分からないときはそのままエラーメッセージでググって、そのエラーメッセージがどういう状況のときに発生するかを調べるのも直接的な解決にはならなくても1つの方法だと思います。そのうちに発生パターンが分かってくると自分で間違いに気付けるようになるかもしれません。